# Updating the same record in database based on the for loop

Tags: java, sql, xml

I have this case where a document with status F, needs to be saved in table LOGS, with the name of the file.

My table should have the following representation:

```
ID: Incremented
FILE:  fileNameWithOutExt (name of the file)
ERROR: errorCode
```

However all the documents within the same file having the same status, need to be inserted in the same record as so:

```
ID: 1
FILE:test
ERROR: id:5,id:9,id:10
```

My if status statement is within a for loop that's passing on all children in an xml file. The ones with status F need to be concatenated within the same record.

```
if(status.equals("F")){
    elemValue = element.getChild("id").getValue();
    String fileNameWithExt = f.getName();
    String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileNameWithExt);
    saveLogs(fileNameWithOutExt, elemValue);
}

private void saveLogs(String fileNameWithOutExt, String elemValue){
    String errorCode = "id:"+ elemValue;
    String query = "INSERT INTO LOGS (FILE,ERROR)VALUES ('"+fileNameWithOutExt+"','"+errorCode+"')";
    String content = "";
    content = SqlTool.selectOneString("DB", query);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could'nt to an update only with an insert instruction. 
Try to see the update instruction and the simply method is to use a SQL script like :

```
UPDATE MyTable SET FieldA=@FieldA WHERE Key=@Key

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT INTO MyTable (FieldA) VALUES (@FieldA)
```